# Combobox value to code

Tags: combobox, pascal

I'm a Pascal newbie and I already read some stuff about it, but it is still pretty hard for me. I want to create a simple password generator, and adjust the number of characters.

I found a function that actually generates the random password for me, which is this:

```
function RandomPassword(PLen: Integer): string;
var
str: string;
begin
Randomize;
//string with all possible chars
str    := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
Result := '';
repeat
Result := Result + str[Random(Length(str)) + 1];
until (Length(Result) = PLen)
end;
```

This is the code that prints the string to the Memo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Caption := RandomPassword(10);
end;
```

I also got a TComboBox, and I want to use the value from the combobox to chose the number of characters (6-32). The number of characters is in this case 10 but I want to use the value from the Combobox instead of a predetermined number. Who can help me? I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the combobox value like this:

`RandomPassword(StrToInt(ComboBox.Items[ComboBox.ItemIndex]))`

`ComboBox.ItemIndex` returns the index of select combobox item

`ComboBox.Items[]` is used to select a item in the combobox.

`StrToInt()` is used cause the combobox value is a string and you have to change it to integer

Comment: @Permambuco Okay thanks for your response ! However, I don't know how to implement it into the code. Basically what I need is that the 10 in after RandomPassword will be the value from the Combobox, so if I click 10 it will be 10 characters etc. Do you know how I can fix this? I just don't see to understand how I can do it.

Comment: You can use itemindex as noted above, or the combobox.text property which always mirrors the current combobox.itemindex. Since combobox lines are text based the text will be '10'. So: myInteger := StrToInt( Combobox.Text ) gives back an integer value of the string '10' which you can then use.